# Grunt-injector ignore css file from bower dependency

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-injector in a new projets. It set up to add all bower dependency to the index.html file.

I have ionic in my dependencies, and I use it only for the javascript file and not the css. So I would like that grunt-injector don't add the ionic css file in my project.

here's my configuration:

```
injector: {
  options: {
    addRootSlash: false,
    ignorePath: 'app/',
    bowerPrefix: 'bower',
  },
  bowerDependencies: {
    files: {
     'app/index.html': ['bower.json'],
  }
}
```

I could do it by modifying ionic/bower.json:

```
"main": [
  //"css/ionic.css",
  "fonts/*",
  "js/ionic.js",
  "js/ionic-angular.js"
]
```

But of course, I would prefer not to do that

Answer (score 0):

Might help, but I found out gulp-injector is just compiling all CSS files between `<!-- bower:css --> ... <!-- endbower -->`

An other task is in charge of reading my bower file and edit index.html, it is [wiredep plugin](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep).

So if like me you used an already prepared scaffolding, look for this task (here gulp) :

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
    log('Wiring the bower dependencies into the html');

    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
    var index = paths.client + 'index.html';

    return gulp.src(index)
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: './bower_components/',
            bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
            exclude: ['bower_components/foundation/css/foundation.css',
                        'bower_components/toastr/toastr.css'],
            ignorePath: '../..' // bower files will be relative to the root
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.client));
});
```

By defining excluse, your will force it to ignore such files, without editing your packages in bower :D